# Boostrap mix with grid to equal height of row inside .col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I want to set my code to auto-calculate equal height in inside of .col, because for example inside .col I have `<h2>` and `<p>` which could have different number of rows, so height of this element will be different for every .col, I would like to get same height for all rows inside .col.

I tried to use flexbox utilities, but I didn't find a solution, so I am wondering if grid will help me get what I want to get, but I don't know if display: grid inherits height of flexbox elements?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="header-bottom-box">
        <h2>Projektowanie <b>stron</b></h2>
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://irson.linuxpl.eu/images/projektowanie-stron.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Projektowanie stron">
        </div>
        <p>Projektowanie oraz tworzenie serwisów internetowych.</p>
        <div class="text-right">
          <a href="/oferta.html">więcej</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="header-bottom-box">
        <h2>Pozycjonowanie <b>stron</b></h2>
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://irson.linuxpl.eu/images/pozycjonowanie-stron.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Pozycjonowanie stron">
        </div>
        <p>Zwiększ pozycję swojej strony www w wynikach wyszukiwania.</p>
        <div class="text-right">
          <a href="/oferta.html">więcej</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="header-bottom-box">
        <h2>Outsourcing <b>IT</b></h2>
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="http://irson.linuxpl.eu/images/outsourcing-it.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Outsourcing IT">
        </div>
        <p>Outsourcing informatyczny Profesjonalna opieka informatyczna dla firm.</p>
        <div class="text-right">
          <a href="/oferta.html">więcej</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRweow

I thought about using display: grid to .header-bottom-box and equal height of inside element.

EDIT
I tried to use GIRD:

[image]

And it works like I want to, but I don't know why I get this white space, how to delete it?

Comment: What whitespace? It's unclear from your screenshot what about your output is undesirable.

Answer (score -1):

this is normal sir,
this all happen because of last col. text is less then first and second.

Comment: I know that, but how to equal height of the heigest and set it to all?